# How to display nodes in a view, each row using a preselected view mode ?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I would like to create a view that displays a number of nodes, each using its own chosen view mode.

I've installed the [Display Suite module](http://drupal.org/project/ds) and created a number of view modes. Using the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views), I've created a view that displays a number of entities/nodes and I can set a view mode for each row, or a default view mode for all rows.

However, I would like the view to somehow use the view mode that has been selected when creating the content itself (under the display settings tab).

So far I have no idea how to achieve this. Could anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the view mode for each entity (e.g. in a field).

Implementing [hook_entity_view_mode_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7) you can override the view mode:

```
function mymodule_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'node') {
    $entity = $context['entity']
    if (get the view mode of $entity) {
      $view_mode = 'custom_view_mode';
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to do a check to run this in your view only, otherwise this will affect the node everywhere.